# Jquery clearInterval for animation + display: none, isn't working properly

Tags: jquery

I have a flashing message bar where it will flash on a simple event, when the user presses the message-bar, the message will disappear (I need display none for this.)

so when the event was init => message bar is blinking (good) => pressing the message bar makes it disappear but then it goes again into the interval animation loop => press it again, disappears yet **again** it revives itself, only on the third click this zombie of an animation dies out, and never comes back (I waited for like a good few seconds to see if it comes back to life.)

What kind of sorcery is this?

Here is my Javascript/Jquery:

```
var timer;

$("a[href='#top']").click(function () {
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
  $(".messages").css('display', 'block').append(
      "<p style='left: 150px;color: red; font-size: 24px;'>You are now on top</p>"
  );
  $('.messages').click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).css('display', 'none');

  });
  function blinker(){
    $(".messages").fadeOut(1200);
    $(".messages").fadeIn(1200);
  }
  timer = setInterval(blinker, 1000);
```

Comment: This is really not a good way to do what you want, shall offer you better approach.

Comment: @skobaljic I would like to understand JavaScript behavior, I could use closures too, please explain why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: This is for sure not your complete code, it has syntax errors (missing closing brackets). But, nevertheless, we'd need the respective HTML containing the mentioned elements `a[href='#top']` and `.messages`. First hint: You are assigning new/additional click handlers to all `.message` elements on every click on the `a[href='#top']` element. Every one of those handlers will execute on every click. Additionally, what do you mean by `presses the bar`? Which bar?

Comment: @devnull69 I have fixed 'bar' to 'message-bar' I'm guessing you didn't read the next lines so you weren't able to deduce that it was a typo and I meant message-bar. Re the JavaScript, if you know javascript you don't need any HTML. This is pure JavaScript.

Comment: `if I knew Javascript` I would tell you that you are manipulating HTML elements with it and assigning event handlers to HTML elements. So there is a direct link to the HTML and it is very much important how this HTML looks like. Another question: You are only talking about clicking the message-bar, but what is `a[href='#top']` then?

Comment: `a[href='#top']` is the event

Answer (score 1):

You set several intervals **inside** the `onclick` event. Move it out of that function. Still, after we place correct code, you still have issues with the interval you set, please look at comments inside:

```
var timer;
var messages = $('.messages');
messages.click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).hide();
});
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    messages.html(
        "<p style='left: 150px;color: red; font-size: 24px;'>You are now on top</p>"
    ).show();
    function blinker() {
        messages.fadeOut(1200, function() {
            /* This happens 1200ms after fadeOut() started, no matter if timer is on or off: */
            messages.fadeIn(1200);
        });
    };
    timer = setInterval(blinker, 1000);
    /* If you click the message in first second, than everything works as you expected */
});
```

Better approach would be to use CSS class for fading:

```js
var messages = $('.messages');
messages.click(function() {
    messages
     .hide()
        .removeClass('loop_fade');
});
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    messages
     .addClass('loop_fade')
        .html(
            "<p style='left: 150px;color: red; font-size: 24px;'>You are now on top</p>"
        ).show();
});
```

```css
.loop_fade {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 2.4s linear infinite;
    animation: fadeinout 2.4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <div class="messages"></div>
</div>
<a href="#top">Go top</a>
```

**[JSFiddle Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/o7naq5fm/)**.

**EDIT:**

If you want a JS solution, than this will work:

```js
var timer;
var messages = $('.messages');
messages.click(function() {
    messages.stop();
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).hide();
});
function blinker() {
    messages.fadeToggle(1200);
};
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    messages.html(
        "<p style='left: 150px;color: red; font-size: 24px;'>You are now on top</p>"
    ).show();
    timer = setInterval(blinker, 1201);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <div class="messages"></div>
</div>
<a href="#top">Go top</a>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjdm9rvz/).

Comment: +1 for the awesome answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue as I want to produce this in Jquery alone, without any css, I would like to learn how to immediately stop the animation on click. thanks for the effort skolbajic.

Comment: Well I tried to explain why, shall add an edit for JS solution.